# How can I make triangles mesh into a convex polygons?

Tags: c#, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a mesh of triangles. Triangles has different "colors". Like this:

[image]

What I need to get is the optimised mesh, where excessive triangles are merged into a convex polygons. Like this:

[image]

Can some one give me a link on some algorithms to acomplish that? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm using C#.

Comment: I've tried to merge two adjacent triangles and then adding more triangles to the polygon, each time checking, is the resulting polygon convex? This method works but the result is very nonoptimal. Preferably I need some algorithm, that can give me the most optimal result. Like the mesh optimization algorithm. But I would be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Is it important that the resulting shapes use only the edges that are present in the original mesh, or can you add edges as required?

Answer (score 1):

The Hertel-Mehlhorn Algorithm is the standard approach for doing this; it can be summarized as

1. Start with a triangulation of polygon P;
2. remove an inessential diagonal
3. repeat.

(from http://www.philvaz.com/compgeom/)

This works in polynomial time, and has a bounds on optimality, although it isn't necessarily the most optimal.

In your case, you'd modify step #2 by not considering diagonals between triangles of different colors.

One heuristic that generally produces "nicer looking" pieces is to merge the longest diagonal at each step.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any links to algorithms to solve this problem, but I think a better approach than building the convex polygons up a triangle at a time might be to first merge the triangles into the largest simple polygons (i.e.: they can be concave, but without holes) you can, and then splitting these large polygons down into their convex constituents.

You know which vertices these splits will occur at due to the internal angle being greater than 180 degrees, then you just need to select the incident edge along which to split. The precise method of selecting an optimal edge to split along is not a simple problem, but a reasonable heuristic might be to maximise the number of <180 degree internal angles after the split.

Comment: The thing is that one of the best algorithms to create convex polygons out of a concave polygon is Hertel-Mehlhorn's algorithm (as mentioned in a previous reply), which needs to first split the polygon in triangles anyway, so it is counter-productive to merge the triangles anyway.