# Flood-fill algorithm to define convex areas

Tags: algorithm, math

I am looking to try and create a flood-fill type algorithm, but one which will break the space into convex regions.

In terms of what my application has in terms of data, all it has is a grid of squares where each square contains connections to the surrounding squares in the cardinal direction. If a square is blocked or invalid in some way, then the square I'm testing won't have a connection in that direction. Screenshot below illustrates what I mean, where black squares are invalid and represent the boundaries of objects:

[image]

What I want to do now is try to come up with an algorithm which means I can tag each grid square as belonging to a convex region, ideally with as few areas as possible (i.e. favouring larger convex areas rather than lots of little fragments). Something like the below where each colour represents a different convex region:

[image]

Is there a known algorithm for this? I've looked at a few flood-fill algorithms, but none of them seem to be able to form convex shapes like this.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. The areas are not really convex. All those sawtooth boundaries kill the convexity right away.  You need to define the (pseudo)-convexity more precisely. For example, it is very unclear why the small magenta triangle cannot be green. 2. Your second image clearly shows that the greedy approach doesn't work: if you cut the southern tim of the blue triangle, you may join yellow and green shapes together.

Comment: @user58697 Yes, you're right, I didn't fully explain the scenario properly. The sawtooth edges are fine: I will use a separate algorithm to create straight lines from those. By "convex" I mean "convex if you draw a line through the centre of the edge voxels".

I drew the above by hand as a means to illustrate what I'm trying to do, so I may have applied my own biases when knocking it up, which explains the magenta triangle (you're right, probably could just be part of the green).

I'm not trying to create exactly the above image: I want to create something that produces similar results.

Comment: This looks like you're trying to build some kind of [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)

Comment: Are the lines from your black rectangles guaranteed to be always at 45° like in this example? This might make the problem much easier if that's true.

Comment: @Stef No, the black shapes will be completely arbitrary. They could be any shape (including non-convex shapes).

You're right that the voronoi diagram is similar to what I want to achieve in a way. The challenge is that the black shapes are static and don't "push back", and I don't have a set of points to expand out from, so I need a way to stop the expansion flooding around corners.

Comment: Related: [How can I make triangles mesh into a convex polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331968/how-can-i-make-triangles-mesh-into-a-convex-polygons). Suggestion: (1) Triangulate the area outside the black shapes; (2) Apply the algorithm suggested at the related question's answers to merge the triangles into larger convex polygons.

Answer (score 0):

K-means clustering can be used to try to find some interesting partitions.

Feel free to read more details here ([https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~schmidtm/Courses/340-F17/L9.pdf](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Eschmidtm/Courses/340-F17/L9.pdf))

Someone mentioned in the comments, you application look somehow like a Voronoi diagram.

[image]